# How to display an image in the ng-grid img column on the basis of button click

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, mouseclick-event

```
I am having a grid, its getting its data from JSON file. There is a column that displays images already,Now I want those images should change to some image for the respective row on button click present in that row.

Refer the link,4th column Severity has images I need a column consisting of buttons next to it, and by clicking on that it should change  the image of Severity column to green one.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Paa9npnVbWhNSmAdfkSf?p=preview

```
Please help me resolve this guys.
Thanks.
```

Comment: Show us what you already have

Comment: I have done the respective edits,could you pls help now.

Comment: Isnt there anybody who can help? Please help me out guys I need to accomplish it, stuck at it from long